# How to check whether the li has class Active?

Tags: twig

I want to add Active class to first li instance through twig without using JS, jQuery or anything else.
How can i achieve that?

Thanks in advance

```
<ul class="header-search-list" id="streetInputList">
   {% for streetOption in streets %}
       <li data-label-for="{{ streetOption.id }}" style="display: none;">{{ streetOption.name }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: if first key equals zero you can do this `{% for key, streetOption in streets %}  {% if key == 0 %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add the class `active` to the first element in your loop, u could use the `loop` variable, e.g.

```
<ul class="header-search-list" id="streetInputList">
   {% for streetOption in streets %}
       <li data-label-for="{{ streetOption.id }}" {% if loop.first %} class="Active"{% endif %} style="display: none;">{{ streetOption.name }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/mxvv9c)

Comment: `loop.first` for the win